# Datatable get data attribute on click row

Tags: datatables

I use datatable

A typical row is

```
<tr>
      <td data-id="1">Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
</tr>
```

I created an example

http://jsfiddle.net/hb7v1mgy/

Init of the table

```
 var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: true
  });
```

When I click on a row, I would like to get data attritube id, actually I get column value (Tiger, System...)

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    //get only value of td... not data attribute
    var data = table.row(this).data();
});
```

Comment: Check out the datatables.net-select plugin (which is developed by dt authors) for this purpose. https://www.npmjs.com/package/datatables.net-select

Comment: document is not very speaking https://datatables.net/reference/event/select#Examples

Comment: I had my troubles with the documentation as well, but console.logging the selected row's data might help you get started: `table.on('select', function (e, dt, type, indexes) { console.log(table.rows(indexes).data()) });`

Comment: Just remember that `select` event only gives you the last selected row(s). You will have to calculate the **list of selected rows** by yourself in case of multiselect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your click method

```
var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
var id = tr.children("td:eq(0)").attr('data-id')
```

you don't need select plugin...